# Работа с файлами txt в java (создание песенника)

Tags: java, android, файлы

Возникла очень большая необходимость написать что-то вроде песенника под Android. И при этом возникла проблема с файлами txt. Хотелось бы узнать как список текстовиков (песни) можно отобразить на главном экране приложения с возможностью переходить к самому тексту. И важно чтобы был какой-нибудь маломальский поиск по ним. Понимаю, что задача грандиозная, но не очень хотелось бы полагаться на фриланс. Хотелось бы разобраться в этом самому. Хотелось бы узнать также есть ли какие-то статьи по этому поводу. Любое слово мне поможет. Огромное спасибо заранее!

Comment: Судя по вашему вопросу, вы ждете что вам дадут код готового приложения) Открывайте поисковик, ищите профильные ресурсы, учитесь и по мере возникновения непонятных вопросов, задавайте их сюда.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Список песен можно отображать в [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview).
За названия песни в списке можно взять название самого txt файла с отрезанным расширением.
Можно создать класс, например `SongFile`, в котором будут два поля `name` и `path`. Получить список файлов в директории (к примеру в Internal Storage нашего приложения). Потом передать список `List<SongFile>` в адаптер `RecyclerView`, поле name будет выступать в качестве названия, а при нажатии на файл будем брать path и открывать новое activity передав через intent path файла, далее нужно прочитать текст из файла и отобразить его в `TextView`. `TextView` поместить в `ScrollView` для прокрутки текста.

Пример получения файлов из директории [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8647397/6850236) (для Internal Storage разрешения не нужны).
Лёгкий способ убрать расширение у файла [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/990408/6850236).
Как прочитать текст из файла [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14250033/6850236).